# How can I delete firebase nodes with many children?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have a lot of child nodes.

I can read and delete all nodes, but this method takes a lot of time, and it it useless.

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.Child ("whoisonline").removevaluasync
```

But I get this error

> Firebase Database error: Data to write exceeds the maximum size that can be modified with a single request.